# what is the difference between JsonType.class and JsonBinaryType.class in hypersistence-utils

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to map **jsonb** (postgresql type) in spring boot 3, spring data jpa 3.* and hibernate 6.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
private UUID id;

private String title;

// both of them work for jsonb. I thought JsonType only for json.
//@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class) 
//@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
private String content;

}
```

I had experience with hypersistence-utils, I used to do   @Type(JsonType.class) for json type and   @Type(JsonBinaryType.class) for jsonb.

Recently I tested jsonb with both of them and they are working properly, which is strange to me. when I worked with hibernate 5.* I had to explicitly define whether it is json type or jsonb.

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
```

or for jsonb

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
```

Question is, why @Type(JsonType.class) works for jsonb in hibernate 6?

And Question in general, Do you guys still use hypersistence-utils or switched to @JdbcTypeCode which is new in hibernate 6?